# What are the advantages of the Confluent's Kakfa Avro serializers?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I can't seem to find clear in the docs what are the advantages of using AvroKafkaSerializer (that have schema support) vs serializing the object "manually" in code and sending them as bytes/string ?

Maybe schema check when producing a new message? What are the others ?

Comment: https://www.confluent.io/blog/schema-registry-kafka-stream-processing-yes-virginia-you-really-need-one/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A message schema is a contract between a group of client applications producing and consuming messages. Schema validation is required when you have many independent applications that need to agree on a specific format, in order to exchange messages reliably.

If you also add a Schema Registry into the picture, then you don't need to include the schema in all your services or every single message, but you will get it from the common registry, with the additional support of schema evolution and validation rules (i.e. backward compatibility, versioning, syntax validation). It is one of the fundamental components in event driven architectures (EDA).

Comment: Thanks, I understand the benefits of schema and I understand Schema Registry is the single point of truth but what I don't understand is how the KafkaAvroSerializer uses it.
Does it check every message before sending it with the schema registry?

Comment: For every message, the serializer [retrieves the schema from the registry](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/6.1.x/avro-serializer/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/serializers/AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java#L78-L105) to do the seralization. That way, you only need to have the schema id, resulting in a much smaller message payload. The [schema is also cached](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/6.1.x/schema-serializer/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/serializers/AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.java#L194) to avoid contacting the registry on every message.

Comment: I think my confusion came from the fact that it looks like in all cases the schema has to be available locally (from the record object in these serializers.
So these serializers don't download the schema from the registry with the purpose of having it, they do it in under to compare them and do compatibility checks. And only de DEserializers actually download it so they can have it and deserialize.

Comment: Correct. The Deserializer talks with the Schema Registry only when receving a schema id it hasn't already seen.